# When CrmServiceClient AuthType is set to AD it uses my ID instead of UN and PW sent

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I'm using the following tutorial:
[crmservice tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/quick-start-org-service-console-app)

In the AuthType when I put AD, no matter what user name and password I put, the ID it returns is always my own ID.

However I need the connection to use the credentials I'm passing because I will be deploying the app to another server, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show how you've implemented that tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if you use:

```
AuthType = AD
```

No matter what credentials you put it will try to authenticate using the service account running the app. I've included "Domain", since that will force the domain to actually use and attempt to validate the credentials:

```
Domain = Napster
```

If you're in an intranet type environment finding the domain can be tricky but for my organization if you look in the Dynamics app the domain is part of the URL or the username as such:

```
Napster\BenClyde
```

Lastly the trickiest part was figuring out the username wasn't just for example "BenClyde" as shown above, it was actually the email:

```
UserName = BenClyde@napster.net
```

Hope this helps and saves someone hours of debugging!